# Error downloading GSE dataset

Tags: geoquery, gse

I've installed GEOquery with

```r
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("GEOquery")
library(GEOquery)
```

then I ran the command

```r
GSE68808 <- getGEO("GSE68808")
```

but it resulted in..

```r
Found 1 file(s)
GSE68808_series_matrix.txt.gz
trying URL 'https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE68nnn/GSE68808/matrix/GSE68808_series_matrix.txt.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4138819 bytes (3.9 MB)
downloaded 3.9 MB

error: 'C:\Users\(myname)\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUp5Sv7\file8e844a7a59bc' does not exist.
```

ㅜㅜ

How can I solve this? thanks.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it has answered your question

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some problem with your "platform specific tempdir" that is used by getGEO's `destdir` parameter. See `?getGEO` for more info on the `destdir` parameter.

Try

```
GSE68808 <- getGEO("GSE68808", destdir = getwd())
```